# How to convert the SQLs of the symfony development bar to the MySQL SQLs?

Tags: symfony1, propel

How to convert the SQLs of the symfony development bar to the MySQL SQLs? I'm using propel.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if what you want is to what what SQL code your propel objects are generating for MySQL, try something like this

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(....);
$c->addJoin(...);
etc
```

to see the code generated, you call

```
echo $c->toString();
```